# Use custom method for getResources.getString(R.string.test) inside another method

Tags: android

First of all, I know separately how to make custom method to show Toast & show String which extend from resource.
See:

```
private void showToast(CharSequence text) {
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

And for Extend String Resource:

```
private void setStringResource(int resource) {
        getResources().getString(resource);
    }
```

But, I want to use something like this:

```
showToast(setStringResource(R.string.please_check_connection));
```

And, it gives compiler error.

How can I do that? Please reply fast. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling your `setStringResource`, you aren't returning any value. Modify your method to the following:

```
private String setStringResource(int resource) {
    return getResources().getString(resource);
}
```

Now when you call this method when creating your `Toast`, the method returns a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to the following:

```
  private void showToast(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} 





private String setStringResource(int resource) {

        return getResources().getString(resource);
 }.
```

Comment: Oops sorry just edited your answer by mistake - I though it was mine....

Comment: @Isaac BTW, was this answer right? CharSqq to String?

Comment: setStringResource method return string but your showToast() method accepts CharSequence so you have to change the parameter if you change the signature of setStringResource(). This should be the right answer

Comment: @EndUser Thanks again!